# Post data from html editor to controller action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I am using `jquery.cleditor.js` plugin for html editor in my mvc application and it is working fine. Now I want to post the editor value to controller action but here I am getting the following exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client 
    (NewContentPage.PageContents="<STRONG>dafs </STRON...").
```

If someone has idea then, please guide me to do this.

Comment: what version of: IIS, .NET Framework, ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: 4.0 .net framework with mvc 2 and testing this on my local machine

Comment: Jon, I found the solution: add <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in under system.web tag in web.config file and add  [ValidateInput(false)] on the action method of controller

Answer (score 23):

If you add `ValidateInput` attribute with `false` it will allow you to submit HTML. Just be aware that you are turning of validation for all of the properties in the viewModel

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult DoStuff(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    //...
}
```

If you are using .NET 4 you'll also have to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`
in your web.config file.

---

If you are using MVC 3 you don't have to add the `ValidateInput` attribute to the controller action you can add `AllowHtml` attribute to the property in the viewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

This allows HTML for `prop2` but the rest of the `MyViewModel` will be validated.